# Why is convergence radius of Taylor series the distance to nearest singularity?

Tags: complex-analysis

This has been driving me crazy and I can't find a satisfying answer on the internet. If a complex function $f$ has a singularity at $z=a$, then its Taylor series at $z=0$ will converge inside the disk with radius $|a|$. So far so good. But why can't the Taylor series, considered as an independent power series, converge on a larger disk? All proofs I found say that this would cause a contradiction because the Taylor series would be analytic at $z=a$ while $f$ isn't. But if we consider the Taylor series as a general power series, it's not necessarily equal to $f$ at that point. Would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: by analytic continuation (or if you wish by the identity theorem), since $f$ is the Taylor series on a small disc, it must be the same Taylor series on any open set where the Taylor series converges

Comment: Why is this true 'by analytic continuation'?

Comment: if two analytic functions are equal on a (connected) open set, they are equal on any larger (connected) open set where they are defined

Comment: Oh, I remember! Thanks a lot, this was really helpful!

Comment: happy to be of help

Comment: You need to add the word analytic to "complex function $f$".  It is not true for non-analytic functions.  Being analytic is a tremendous constraint on a function.  One thing it means is that the function equals its Taylor series where the Taylor series converges.  What you need is that the Taylor series converges on a disk, not on some differently shaped domain.